# If a column has a string such as "apple", then another column value ="red"

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c("apple","computer,mouse","mac,pen","light"),b=c(2011,2012,2013,2014))

col1 <- rep(NA,4),df1<- (df1,col1)
```

If row in `df1[i]` is apple ,the `col1[i]` is red

I do not know how to use function(s) to match the string.

Comment: There is no question being asked here.  Just a bunch of words that fail to  form a sentence.  And what on earth is `col1 <- rep(NA,4),df1<- (df1,col1)` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to find 'apple' in the 'a' column, use that to update the 'col1'.

```
df1$col1[grep("apple", df1$a)] <- "red"
df1
#               a    b col1
#1          apple 2011  red
#2 computer,mouse 2012 <NA>
#3        mac,pen 2013 <NA>
#4          light 2014 <NA>
```

---

I would assume the the OP's code

```
df1 <- cbind(df1, col1)
```

Comment: I thought the same that the OP made a mistake instead using cbind ! however, great answer, I like :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the input of OP is the following

```
 df1<- structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("apple", 
"computer,mouse", "light", "mac,pen"), class = "factor"), b = c(2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014), col1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "col1"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

a possible option is the following

```
index <- which(df1$a == "apple") 
df1$col1[index] <- "red"

> df1
#               a    b col1
#1          apple 2011  red
#2 computer,mouse 2012 <NA>
#3        mac,pen 2013 <NA>
#4          light 2014 <NA>
```